# Transit-AS, AS-Path filtering

Tags: bgp

I have the following situation:

RouterA has an eBGP peering with a transit provider X and an eBGP session with a downstream customer with ASN 12345 as an example.  I've requested from provider X that they modify their as-path filter to allow updates from the customer ASN 12345.  I've also modified the filters on our RouterA to allow their prefix and ASN in our as-path filter so things should be working.

On routerA, I see the received prefix from them fine however it is not being advertised to transit provider X and the prefix isn't working from the outside world.

From RouterA, I can ping various configured interfaces on the customer equipment on the new prefix.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.  In the transit provider's route-map, there was a match for a prefix-list that was denying prefix advertisements for certain blocks.

Correcting the prefix-list fixed my issue and all is good.